# PHP inheritance and different parameters in childs

Tags: php, generics

I'm trying to create something similar to generics in PHP.
I want other programmers to be able to create their own supported data types, so I used design patterns called Fasade, Adapter and Factory.

I have a main class that is a factory that creates concrete objects that share a uniform interface.

Factory:

```
class ListFactory
{
    public function __construct(private readonly array $listClasses) {}

    public function create(string $type)
    {
        return new ($this->listClasses[$type]);
    }
}
```

The **$listClasses** variable is ideally injected via DI and contains all classes that implement the ListInterface in the format **['type' => 'className']**...

So now I have an interface that defines only one method so far:

ListInterface:

```
interface ListInterface
{
    public function add($item): static;
}
```

and then so far I have two concrete classes that implement this interface:

IntList:

```
class IntList implements ListInterface
{
    private array $value = [];

    public function add($item): static
    {
        if (!is_int($item)) { /* throw exception */}
        $this->value[] = $item;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

String List:

```
class StringList implements ListInterface
{
    private array $value = [];

    public function add($item): static
    {
        if (!is_strnig($item)) { /* throw exception */}
        $this->value[] = $item;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

the question is how to make it so that I don't have to validate the data type with if, but I could write, for example, in the StringList class the **add** function like this:

```
public function add(string $item): static
{
    $this->value[] = $item;
    return $this;
}
```

If I try to do it now, I get an error like that **add method in the StringList class must be compatible with the add method inside the ListInterface**

Thanks

Comment: `is_strnig` is wrong. It has to be `is_string`.

Answer (score 0):

The signature **must** match as your error message stated. To make it easy for every add function of that interface you could use a trait and do the type checking in there.

```
interface ListInterface {
    public function add(mixed $item): static;
}

trait ListTrait {
    public function add(mixed $item): static
    {
        switch(gettype($item)) {
            case 'integer':
                if(!$this instanceof IntList) throw new Exception("Int expected");
                break;
            case 'string':
                if(!$this instanceof StringList) throw new Exception("String expected");
                break;
        }
        $this->value[] = $item;
        return $this;
    }
}

class IntList implements ListInterface
{
    use ListTrait;
    private array $value = [];
}

class StringList implements ListInterface
{
    use ListTrait;
    private array $value = [];
}
```

Example usage

```
$i = new IntList();
$i->add(123);
$i->add("123"); // Exception!

$s = new StringList();
$s->add("123");
$s->add(123); // Exception!
```